# XML Item data to an "array"?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file with plenty of lines like this:

```
<RibbonItem VisualSPIcon="http://teamtmnas.corp.tmnas.com/sites/VisualSPFarmHub/siteassets/1033/icons/icpng_16x16.gif" VisualSPSize="Medium" VisualSPScope=";#Tasks;#AnnouncementList;#DiscussionBoard;#Events;#IssueTracking;#Contacts;#Links;#GenericList;#ProjectTasks;#" VisualSPPermissions=";#AnyListPermission;#AnyListSettingPermission;#AnySiteSettingPermission;#" VisualSPUniqueId="9de02f1d-55b3-4ae3-a6bb-25d7421450c8" Title="Tasks quick reference">
```

What I would like to do is to take the information in **VisualSPScope** and extract it for use in a tag cloud in MS SharePoint 2010.  I'm new to XSLT and XPath haven't been able to figure this out yet.

Thanks in advance,
Larry

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "extract it for use". What is the output format you need? Structured as XML, plain text?

Comment: I would like to use each value in that one field as an element.  Plain text is fine.

Comment: Please _show_ the exact expected output by editing your question. Also, try to be clear with the terminology. There are no arrays or fields in XSLT.

Comment: You will need to use a named template (or an extension function) to tokenize the input - see, for example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905766/remove-recurring-values-from-string/21911068#21911068

Comment: @MathiasMüller "*try to be clear with the terminology.*" Speaking of that, *plain text* is not an antonym of XML. XML **is** plain text - i.e. it is not bold or italic or *styled* in any other way.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I did not say that to be nit-picking. I meant to be helpful and find what out what the OP's intent is. _Of course_ XML is plain text as we both know. Still, in some sense of the word there is a distinction between the two (e.g. the different output methods of XSLT stylesheets).

Comment: @MathiasMüller "* I did not say that to be nit-picking.*" Well, maybe I did. I do that sometimes. ;-) But truly, "plain text" is taken. How about "XML or just plain old text"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I don't see the point in arguing with you if we both know perfectly well that XML is plain text. I'd be willing to insert "old" next time - if it did not seem to me that there is nothing "new" about XML as opposed to "old" plain text. I would appreciate if you only insisted on discussing terminology if it helps understanding either a question or an answer.